# How to group data weekly for MTD and YTD values

Tags: t-sql, group-by, dateadd

I'm trying to get Weekly MTD and YTD values based of hourly data, but I'm having difficulties achieving this.

This is the data I'm working with:

max(Date) - Last day of the week

ISOWeek - Week in question

Value - The data I'm trying to sum

```
SELECT MAX(ISOWeek) AS [ISOWeek]
,MAX(Date) AS [Date]
,SUM(Value1) AS [MTD]

FROM Table1

GROUP BY ISOWeek, FORMAT(Date,'yyMM')
ORDER BY ISOWeek DESC
```

This is what that query returns:

```
ISOWeek Date    MTD
29  2020-07-19  367529
28  2020-07-12  367138
27  2020-06-30  103290
27  2020-07-05  266755
26  2020-06-28  346588
25  2020-06-21  337168
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
ISOWeek Date    MTD
29  2020-07-19  261515
28  2020-07-12  184104
27  2020-07-05  103414
26  2020-06-28  432114
25  2020-06-21  346588
```

The data has to be grouped by ISOWeek, if it's a week that dips into two months, I'm only interested in the MTD of the month in which the week ends. We have hundreds of values, so the plan is to create a MTD view and a YTD view. If I can get some help with the MTD one, I can get the other one done.

I'm nearly sure that what I'm after has to do with a WHERE clause and DATEADD but I'm not too sure what it should say.

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Since you `group by` pairs of values you will get a result row for each distinct pair. You seem to want only one result for each ISO week, so that should be the only `group by` column. (At least until your data crosses a year boundary,)

Comment: HABO, you're right, the group by has to be ISOWeek alone but that won't give me a cumulative value per week. I'm not sure what to put in the WHERE clause. The only way I could get close was to add that FORMAT yyMM in the group by too.

Comment: If you group by ISO week (and year) and the `sum` isn't "right" then you'll probably want to use _conditional aggregation_, e.g. `Sum( case when ... end )`, to get the week's value added to the "correct" month (and year). Given incorrect and desired results, but not DDL and sample data, it's a bit hard to help.

Comment: HABO, the sum is correct for the specific week, but it's MTD I'm after. I'm finally starting to get somewhere with MTD  = SUM([Value1]) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, max([Date])), 0)), it still gives me repetitive historical values but it's a start. In any case, I appreciate the help, despite the lack of sample data available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow the rules you would like to apply, but per dates apply the formula to get weekstart/monthend or what you need. Place the date instead of the current date in the example.

Then group by the modified date.

You could build a date dimension where you have the required dates in some columns (first day of month, first day of week,etc.). This way you get a table with all the dates and the matching result for each.

It might be easier/faster to join it on the requried column.

```
declare @monthstart date,
        @monthend date,
        @weekstart date
;
select @monthstart=datefromparts(year(current_timestamp),month(current_timestamp),1);
select @monthend=EOMONTH(getdate(),0);
select @monthstart,@monthend,EOMONTH(getdate(),1) as next_month, EOMONTH(getdate(),-1) as previous_month;
select cast(DATEADD(d,1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,current_timestamp),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as date) as Sunday,
    cast(DATEADD(d,2-case when DATEPART(WEEKDAY,current_timestamp)=1 then 8 else DATEPART(WEEKDAY,current_timestamp) end,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as date) as Monday
;
```